# OpenGL staging buffer to improve Uniform Buffer performance

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

[I read](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/198752-Poor-glMultiDrawElementsIndirect-Performance?p=1283496&viewfull=1#post1283496) that driver seems to put buffers on client side memory, so it comes to me a different idea to manage my uniform buffers.

My uniform buffers work with matrix, materials etc, so they are updated more than once by frame.

The old way was this one :

1. Create uniform buffer using glBufferStorage, and map it with flush_bit.
2. Update a part of this buffer, flush it and drawcall.

My new way could be like that :

1. Create uniform buffer using glBufferData and dynamic (??) hint.
2. Create a little transfer buffer with bl buffer storage and client side hint(thanks to that, I must not flush it?)
3. Update the transfer buffer
4. Copy the transfer buffer to the uniform one.

Do you think it could improve performance?